# 1999 Chevy Cavalier Oil Levels

Tags: chevrolet, oil

I have a bi-fuel 1999 Chevy Cavalier. When the engine is stopped, the oil dipstick reads full. When the engine is running the dipstick consistently reads about 6 inches above the max fill line. It's this normal or does it indicate a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be read after the engine is stopped. You are getting a high level when the engine is running because the crankshaft is more than likely throwing oil up on it as it spins around. What you are seeing is very normal. Just check it with the engine off and you're golden.